# Qt 5.0 Crashes when dragging file over QWidget with parent

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, segmentation-fault

I got a really strange crash when going from qt4.8 to qt 5.0.1 with dragging and dropping. Everything worked fine with the old qt 4.8 but as soon as I went in to qt 5.0 it always seem to crash when dragging a file over the mainwindow.

So I started a totally clean project, created a layout within the centralwidget and then a widget inside the layout. 
The widget tree like this:

Mainwindow - centralWidget - Layout - newWidget

Everytime I drag a file over the window Qt seems to load a lot of libraries to find a template, sure no problem with that (except that it takes some time). Now comes the strange part, when I drop the file (Note no QWidget is not droppable and no special settings at all) the program crashes, this happens everytime and it happens when I drop the file in the window or drag the file outside the window.

It gives me a Segmantation Fault and this disassembler code everytime:

```
            Function: lstrlenA
0x74dcad83  <+0x0006>         jge    0x74dcad6d <lstrcpynA+112>
0x74dcad85  <+0x0008>         sti
0x74dcad86  <+0x0009>         roll   $0x0,(%edx)
0x74dcad89  <+0x000c>         mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x74dcad8c  <+0x000f>         test   %eax,%eax
0x74dcad8e  <+0x0011>         je     0x74dcadc7 <lstrlenA+74>
0x74dcad90  <+0x0013>         andl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
0x74dcad94  <+0x0017>         lea    0x1(%eax),%edx
0x74dcad97  <+0x001a>         mov    (%eax),%cl
0x74dcad99  <+0x001c>         inc    %eax
0x74dcad9a  <+0x001d>         test   %cl,%cl
0x74dcad9c  <+0x001f>         jne    0x74dcad97 <lstrlenA+26>
0x74dcad9e  <+0x0021>         sub    %edx,%eax
0x74dcada0  <+0x0023>         movl   $0xfffffffe,-0x4(%ebp)
0x74dcada7  <+0x002a>         jmp    0x74dcadc9 <lstrlenA+76>
0x74dcada9  <+0x002c>         mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x74dcadac  <+0x002f>         mov    (%eax),%eax
0x74dcadae  <+0x0031>         mov    (%eax),%eax
0x74dcadb0  <+0x0033>         xor    %ecx,%ecx
0x74dcadb2  <+0x0035>         cmp    $0xc00000fd,%eax
0x74dcadb7  <+0x003a>         setne  %cl
0x74dcadba  <+0x003d>         mov    %ecx,%eax
0x74dcadbc  <+0x003f>         ret
0x74dcadbd  <+0x0040>         mov    -0x18(%ebp),%esp
0x74dcadc0  <+0x0043>         movl   $0xfffffffe,-0x4(%ebp)
0x74dcadc7  <+0x004a>         xor    %eax,%eax
0x74dcadc9  <+0x004c>         call   0x74df6fc9 <KERNELBASE!IsNLSDefinedString+1209>
0x74dcadce  <+0x0051>         ret    $0x4
0x74dcadd1  <+0x0054>         int3
0x74dcadd2  <+0x0055>         int3
0x74dcadd3  <+0x0056>         int3
0x74dcadd4  <+0x0057>         int3
0x74dcadd5  <+0x0058>         int3
        Function: lstrcmpW
0x74dcadd6  <+0x0000>         mov    %edi,%edi
0x74dcadd8  <+0x0002>         push   %ebp
0x74dcadd9  <+0x0003>         mov    %esp,%ebp
0x74dcaddb  <+0x0005>         push   %esi
0x74dcaddc  <+0x0006>         mov    0xc(%ebp),%esi
0x74dcaddf  <+0x0009>         push   %edi
0x74dcade0  <+0x000a>         mov    0x8(%ebp),%edi
0x74dcade3  <+0x000d>         push   $0xffffffff
0x74dcade5  <+0x000f>         push   %esi
0x74dcade6  <+0x0010>         push   $0xffffffff
0x74dcade8  <+0x0012>         push   %edi
0x74dcade9  <+0x0013>         push   $0x0
0x74dcadeb  <+0x0015>         push   $0x400
0x74dcadf0  <+0x001a>         call   0x74de2e93 <KERNELBASE!CopySid>
0x74dcadf5  <+0x001f>         test   %eax,%eax
0x74dcadf7  <+0x0021>         jne    0x74dcae54 <lstrcmpW+126>
0x74dcadf9  <+0x0023>         push   $0xffffffff
```

System is: Windows 7 x64
Qt version: Qt 5.0.1 with MinGW compiler

Anyone have any idea about this, seems like a Qt bug or?

Edit: tried to build the small application in Release mode and there it worked fine, so it is something with the compiler. Heres the complete stack trace:

```
Thread 6 (Thread 5248.0x1d48):
#0  0x77121f26 in ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x77121f26 in ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x77153352 in ntdll!RtlCreateTagHeap () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x75ea33aa in KERNEL32!BaseCleanupAppcompatCacheSupport () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x77139ef2 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x77139ec5 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.

Thread 5 (Thread 5248.0x1278):
#0  0x7711fd71 in ntdll!RtlFindSetBits () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x74dd4498 in Sleep () from C:\Windows\syswow64\KernelBase.dll
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x7620d98d in ole32!CoIsOle1Class () from C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x7620d87a in ole32!CoIsOle1Class () from C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x75ea33aa in KERNEL32!BaseCleanupAppcompatCacheSupport () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x77139ef2 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x77139ec5 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.

Thread 4 (Thread 5248.0x1978):
#0  0x77121f26 in ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x77121f26 in ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x77153352 in ntdll!RtlCreateTagHeap () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x75ea33aa in KERNEL32!BaseCleanupAppcompatCacheSupport () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x77139ef2 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x77139ec5 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.

Thread 3 (Thread 5248.0x1d90):
#0  0x77121f26 in ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x77121f26 in ntdll!LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x77153352 in ntdll!RtlCreateTagHeap () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x75ea33aa in KERNEL32!BaseCleanupAppcompatCacheSupport () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x77139ef2 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x77139ec5 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.

Thread 2 (Thread 5248.0x84):
#0  0x7712013d in ntdll!RtlEnableEarlyCriticalSectionEventCreation () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x75ea33aa in KERNEL32!BaseCleanupAppcompatCacheSupport () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x77139ef2 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x77139ec5 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.

Thread 1 (Thread 5248.0x1a10):
#0  0x74dcad97 in lstrlenA () from C:\Windows\syswow64\KernelBase.dll
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x525bb9b9 in D3DStripShader () from C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin\D3DCompiler_43.dll
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00000100 in ?? ()
        qt_meta_stringdata_QPropertyAnimation = {data = {{ref = {atomic = {_q_value = -1}}, size = 18, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 48, static shared_null = {{ref = {atomic = {_q_value = -1}}, size = 0, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 16, static shared_null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, {ref = {atomic = {_q_value = 0}}, size = 0, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 0, static shared_null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}}}, {ref = {atomic = {_q_value = -1}}, size = 12, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 51, static shared_null = {{ref = {atomic = {_q_value = -1}}, size = 0, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 16, static shared_null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, {ref = {atomic = {_q_value = 0}}, size = 0, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 0, static shared_null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}}}, {ref = {atomic = {_q_value = -1}}, size = 12, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 48, static shared_null = {{ref = {atomic = {_q_value = -1}}, size = 0, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 16, static shared_null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, {ref = {atomic = {_q_value = 0}}, size = 0, alloc = 0, capacityReserved = 0, offset = 0, static shared_null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}}}}, stringdata = "QPropertyAnimation\000propertyName\000targetObject\000"}
        qt_meta_data_QPropertyAnimation = {7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12, 610563, 2, 39, 610563, 0}
        QPropertyAnimation::staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x6bae8ff0, stringdata = 0x6bae9a80, data = 0x6bae9ae0, static_metacall = 0x6b788a4e <QPropertyAnimation::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}}
#3  0x19fe0000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x7efdb800 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x76457a36 in wvsprintfW () from C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x003bd676 in HydraDMH!HookMessages () from C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\HydraVision\HydraDMH.dll
No symbol table info available.
warning: (Internal error: pc 0xff in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0xff in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0xff in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0xff in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0xff in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0x0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
```

Edit 2: After a lot of testing I've found that this seems to be an issue with my ATI drivers, the dll "ATI Technologies\HydraVision\HydraDMH.dll" is always in there when the program crashes. I tested the same small project on my laptop that doesn't have ATI and there it works fine. And the crash only occurs when in Debug mode.

Don't really know where to go with this but the drag and drop worked in Qt 4.8.4 so this is probably an issue in Qt 5.0.1.

Comment: We can see it's crashing comparing C-strings, but can you provide a stack trace so we can see where in Qt it is failing?

Comment: I've added the stacktrace, it seems like it's somewhere in the "mingw47_32\bin\D3DCompiler_43.dll" dll where it crashes.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem using QPlottingWidget ( from http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/ ).
It's working on Qt 4.8 but since Qt5, it crashes when I drag curves outside the main Widget.